spline alembic animation not working in cycles render

1st image is the rendered image where the Alembic spline animation are not working and 2nd is the screenshot of the viewport at same frame where splines Alembic animation is working.
How to make sure splines get animated during render as well? ⁠Animation overall

In the Properties Editor > Render tab, > Performance panel, disable Persistent Data.

it is already disabled

any other solution? @L0Lock ?
